# Creating a new column of 1s and 0s as a way to count unique values in R

Tags: r

I would like to add a helper column of 0s and 1s to keep track of unique values based on one or more variables in R Programming.
Sample data:

```r
df<- matrix(c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","D"))
```

and what I would like is:

```r
structure(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L))
```

Comment: Please describe in words what your goal is, rather than in screenshot of excel formula. A little bit of copy/pasteable sample data is always helpful. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data.

Comment: I have added sample data, thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use the following solution:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$Helper <- +!duplicated(df$V1)
df

   V1 Helper
1   A      1
2   A      0
3   A      0
4   B      1
5   B      0
6   C      1
7   D      1
8   D      0
9   D      0
10  D      0
```

Comment: The use of `duplicated` is really elegant here. Nice!

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Upvoted your nice solution too :)

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
# Creating the dataframe:
df <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","D"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(helper = ifelse(row_number()==1, 1,0))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
   id    helper
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 A          1
 2 A          0
 3 A          0
 4 B          1
 5 B          0
 6 C          1
 7 D          1
 8 D          0
 9 D          0
10 D          0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   mutate(Helper = +(rowid(id) == 1))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", 
"D", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `ave`

```
transform(
  as.data.frame(df),
  helper = +(ave(seq_along(V1),V1,FUN = seq_along)==1)
)
```

gives

```
   V1 helper
1   A      1
2   A      0
3   A      0
4   B      1
5   B      0
6   C      1
7   D      1
8   D      0
9   D      0
10  D      0
```

Comment: Never used this great function `ave` so far. Glad you used it so that I could learn.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I believe `duplicated` is the most efficient solution here, as your :)

Comment: Thank you very much but transforming data structure within a call to `transform` is also elegant. If I'm not mistaken it almost does the same thing as `group_by` and `mutate` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using `match` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(result = as.integer(row_number() %in% match(unique(id), id)))

#   id result
#1   A      1
#2   A      0
#3   A      0
#4   B      1
#5   B      0
#6   C      1
#7   D      1
#8   D      0
#9   D      0
#10  D      0
```

In base R -

```
transform(df, result = as.integer(seq(nrow(df)) %in% match(unique(id), id)))
```